# RVM: Incorrect Ruby version referenced after removal

Tags: rvm

Just updated the version of Ruby (1.9.2 to 1.9.3) I have installed but now getting the following error when running `rake`:

```
$ rake
-bash: /Users/mike.simmonds/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rake: /Users/mike.simmonds/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any tips?

Comment: apparently, it's looking for the old ruby. Do you have a symlink somewhere, that points to `/Users/mike.simmonds/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears reinstalling the rake gem has fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a `gem pristine` task failed and you had older rvm, I have already changed the upgrade code to run upgrade for every gem separately and report you list of failed gems.

It's important to read outputs of rvm, even we try to automate things and make things very easy - sometimes there is not much we can do with the available tools.